# Encountered problem SQL Statement ignored and ORA-00947

Tags: sql, oracle

I dont understand the problem it prompt after running my code and dont know how to solve it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reader_workCount
    AFTER INSERT ON BILL
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    WorkCount INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT Count(*),StaffNo into WorkCount
        FROM BILL
        WHERE to_number(to_char(CreatedDate,'mm')) = to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm'))
        GROUP BY StaffNo;
        
        IF (WorkCount > 5)
        THEN
            DELETE BILL
            WHERE BILL.BillNo = :NEW.BillNo;
            raise_application_error(-20900,'Employee is overwork!');
        END IF;
 END;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/id212.png)

Comment: `SELECT Count(*),StaffNo into WorkCount` --> two columns with one returning variable ... The error is due to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from the comments you have fixed the *compilation* error, but you have a big problem still with your logic.

1. Mutation

You are triggering on "BILL" and then trying to DELETE from BILL in the trigger. If you ever get to the situation where that delete needs to run, you'll get a "Table is mutating error". Row level triggers cannot do DML on the table they are working on. That's a larger topic but I suggest you google for "mutating table trigger" and you'll lots of examples/solutions etc.

2. Concurrency.

If two people both insert into BILL at the same time when there are 5 people already for a given staff number, they will *both* see that there is 5 people, they will *both* think that they are OK to insert and at the end of the exercise you will have 6 people for that Staff Number which breaks the rule.  This is because each session cannot see the others uncommitted changes.

This also requires a fair bit of complexity to fix. Some good examples on this here

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=preventing-childless-parent-records